# Unable to type 'i' in terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am unable to type the letter `i` in terminal:
e.g,
When i try to type 
`this is bad`
i get:
`ths s bad`

my `i` key works fine elsewhere though.

also when i type `e` it starts typing `s` repeatedly.

it all happened after i tried to follow [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87061/can-i-make-tab-auto-completion-case-insensitive-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Hi! It would be easier to help if you posted, in your question, the exact configuration changes you made to reach this behavior.

Comment: sorry, i followed all three answers because first two didn't worked so.

i deleted `.inputrc` from home folder and commented the changes in `.bashrc` but couldnt change `/etc/inputrc` so i guess the configuration changes are just because of `/etc/inputrc` configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't anything important in your `.inputrc`, and

```
ls -a ~/.?nputrc
```

doesn't reveal any files other than your `.inputrc`, you can do

```
rm ~/.?nputrc
```

and launch another terminal.

If there is something important in your `.inputrc`, and assuming there is still only one file matching `~/.?nputrc`, and you did `echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' >> ~/.inputrc` from the link you gave, you can undo it with:

```
grep -v 'set complet.on-.gnore-case On' < ~/.?nputrc > ~/f-x-nputrc
mv -v ~/f-x-nputrc ~/.?nputrc
```

Either of these should fix it, if the only file you messed with was your `.inputrc`.